# Is wrapping components in order to place them within their parent's layout a correct approach?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm torn between two design choices. I'll let the code do the talking...

## Approaches

### First approach

#### Navbar component

```js
const NavbarSurface = styled.div`
    height: 100px;
`;

function Navbar() {
    return (
        <NavbarSurface>
            <NavbarLogo />
        </NavbarSurface>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

#### NavbarLogo component

```js
const Logo = styled.div`
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    display: flex;
`

function NavbarLogo() {
    return (
        <Logo>
            <Typography variant={"body2"} color={"textPrimary"} align={"center"} style={{
                margin: "auto"
            }}>
                LOGO
            </Typography>
        </Logo>
    )
}

export default NavbarLogo;
```

### Second approach

#### Navbar component

```js
const NavbarSurface = styled.div`
    height: 100px;
`;

const StyledNavbarLogo = styled(NavbarLogo)`
    height: 100%;
`

function Navbar() {
    return (
        <NavbarSurface>
            <StyledNavbarLogo />
        </NavbarSurface>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

#### NavbarLogo component

```js
const Logo = styled.div`
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 50px;
    display: flex;
`

function NavbarLogo({className}) {
    return (
        <Logo className={className}>
            <Typography variant={"body2"} color={"textPrimary"} align={"center"} style={{
                margin: "auto"
            }}>
                LOGO
            </Typography>
        </Logo>
    )
}

export default NavbarLogo;
```

## Difference

The key difference between the two approaches is that on the second one, the child component (`NavbarLogo`) is released from the responsibility of being placed within the layout the parent component (Navbar) has defined. The child component is wrapped within the parent (`StyledNavbarLogo`) and the `css` associated with the parent (`height: 100%;`) is located within the parent itself.

## My thoughts

I believe the second approach to be the better of the two as it is splitting responsibility between the components according to their functionality and leaves room for changes inside the `Logo` component without it affecting its placement relative to the parent container. At the same time, the second approach introduces an extra `div` which could be considered adding overhead so I'm in a dilemma which way is best.
What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Both of your approaches are almost identical, with the exception of the fact that you are extending styles of NavbarLogo in the second case.**

Also it doesn't create an additional div, `instead just add another className to the NavbarLogo component` which your forward to the Logo component

You can use **any of the two approaches** based on your use case but the second approach gives your more flexibility to provide default styles as well as override it if required from the parent. This is **specially useful if you are using the component at multiple places**.

However if your **component only is used at one place** and is not a generic component, the **first approach works well** and should be preferred to not unnecessarily complicate things